# JavaScript: Unable to get the rgb colors in the squares

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is an RGB guessing game that consists of six squares having random colors on the screen and the user has to select/guess the combination matching the RGB color. Initially, I was setting all the six squares with the given below combination but I am unable to get the output and there's no effect of the javascript file that is included.

```js
var color = [
  "rgb=(255, 0, 0)",
  "rgb=(0, 255, 255)",
  "rgb=(255, 0, 255)",
  "rgb=(255, 255, 0)",
  "rgb=(0, 0, 255)",
  "rgb=(0, 255, 255)"

]

var square = document.querySelector.all(".square");

for (var i = 0; i < square.length; i++) {
  square[i].style.backgroundColor = color[i];
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #232323;
}

.square {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: purple;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  margin: 1.66%;
  float: left;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1> The Great RGB Game</h1>


<div id="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @Ivan the code still isn't effective in changing all the purple squares to the RGB combination specified in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code `document.querySelector.all(".square")` is false you will have to use `querySelectorAll()` function:

```js
var square = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
```

If you'd opened your console you would have seen the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector.all is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
var color = [
  "rgb=(255, 0, 0)",
  "rgb=(0, 255, 255)",
  "rgb=(255, 0, 255)",
  "rgb=(255, 255, 0)",
  "rgb=(0, 0, 255)",
  "rgb=(0, 255, 255)"

];

function convertToHex(str){
  var raw = str.match(/(\d+)/g);
  var hexr = parseInt(raw[0]).toString(16);
  var hexg = parseInt(raw[1]).toString(16);
  var hexb = parseInt(raw[2]).toString(16);
      hexr = hexr.value == 1 ? '0' + hexr: hexr;
      hexg = hexg.length == 1 ? '0' + hexg: hexg;
      hexb = hexb.length == 1 ? '0' + hexb: hexb;
  var hex = '#' + hexr + hexg + hexb;
  return hex;
}

var square = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

for (var i = 0; i < square.length; i++) {
  square[i].style.backgroundColor = convertToHex(color[i]);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #232323;
}

.square {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: purple;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  margin: 1.66%;
  float: left;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1> The Great RGB Game</h1>


<div id="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```